# Show every other tick label on d3 time axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a d3 chart with an x-axis that uses a custom time format:

```
var x = d3.time.scale.utc()
        .domain([start, end])
        .range([0, width]);

var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format.utc.multi([
    ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getUTCDate() != 1; }],
    ["%b", function(d) { return d.getUTCMonth(); }],
    ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
]);

var xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("top")
                .tickFormat(customTimeFormat)
                .innerTickSize(-height)
                .outerTickSize(0)
                .ticks(d3.time.month.utc, 1);
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to have a tick for each month, but only a label for each third month. All I seem to be able to do, however, is to either (a) have a tick and label for each month or (b) have a tick and label for every third month.

How can I specify to draw ticks every month, but only have the labels show up for every third month?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that regardless your x axis using a custom time format.

One solution is simply finding the text in that tick and removing it:

```
var ticks = d3.selectAll(".tick text");
ticks.each(function(_,i){
    if(i%3 !== 0) d3.select(this).remove();
});
```

I'm using the modulo (`i%3`) to get the multiples of 3. You can use any other number you want.

Here is a demo:

```js
var width = 550,
  height = 200;

var data = [{
    month: "Jan"
  },
  {
    month: "Feb"
  },
  {
    month: "Mar"
  },
  {
    month: "Apr"
  },
  {
    month: "May"
  },
  {
    month: "Jun"
  },
  {
    month: "Jul"
  },
  {
    month: "Aug"
  },
  {
    month: "Sep"
  },
  {
    month: "Oct"
  },
  {
    month: "Nov"
  },
  {
    month: "Dec"
  },
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.month
  }))
  .range([0, width * 0.95])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,100)")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);

var ticks = d3.selectAll(".tick text");

ticks.each(function(_, i) {
  if (i % 3 != 0) d3.select(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #4e5a64;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In general, this doesn't really work well in the event that you want your tick labels to always occur on the "nicest" tick values, although it's fine for this example

Answer (score 17):

I think tickformats are really helpful here to keep it clean, atleast worked for me.

code is untested but i just want to draw attention to how we can manipulate tickformat.

```
var xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("top")
                .tickFormat((interval,i) => {
                  return i%3 !== 0 ? " ": interval;
                 })
                .innerTickSize(-height)
                .outerTickSize(0)
                .ticks(d3.time.month.utc, 1);
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Labels should be generated initially correct instead of removing or hiding ticks 'after-the-fact'.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I ended up using CSS. Each tick element has two children, `<text>` for the label and `<line>` for the grid-line so you have to select the inner text element and the grid-line will stay in place

```
.tick:nth-child(3n) text {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```