# Remove every other column label on a D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to recreate the following in D3

[image]

And I've got the following so far: http://codepen.io/jpezninjo/pen/dNwmVK

I looked it up and the best I could find was this answer: [Show every other tick label on d3 time axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921226/show-every-other-tick-label-on-d3-time-axis), but I'm not using a class to create each column label. I think the following two lines are the ones that control my labels, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
.range([0, width])
.padding(0.1);

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
```

I'm also trying to figure out how I can put some padding on the left and right of the bars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least two possible ways:

1. Make your X axis a time axis, and use `d3.timeDay.every(2)` to specify *every 2nd day*. That approach is shown here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNdaRB.

   Key part: `var axisBottom = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay).tickArguments([d3.timeDay.every(2)]);`.

   To make this work, I also had to (a) make `d.key` equal to the result from `parseDate` instead of the formatted date string, (b) hard-code a width for the bars instead of using `x.bandwidth()`, and (c) translate the x axis by `width/2 px` to center it under the bars (line 94). Might be nicer ways to do (b) and (c) but I mainly wanted to show `d3.timeDay.every(2)`'s ability ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickArguments)).
2. Use your current approach but apply a style to every 2nd tick. d3 adds some classes automatically so selecting the ticks is easy. This is what they described in the post you linked to. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRLogy?editors=1010

   Key part: `d3.selectAll(".tick text").style("display", function (d, i) { return i % 2 ? "none" : "initial" })`

Comment: Thanks you so much! I really appreciate your explanation as a bonus